# Dynamically switch views in ExtJS 4 grid panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

There is a need to dynamically change a view in **ExtJS 4 grid panel**.

By default grid is displayed as a table, but in my application I need a feature to switch grid from table view to *tiles* (or *cards*) view. Below I tried to represent how it should look like.

```
 Normal view:                               Tiles view:
 ======================================     ====================================
 | Name       | Description           |     | Name       | Description         |
 ======================================     ====================================
 | Name 1     | First description   |^|     |  ------     ------     ------  |^|
 |----------------------------------|X|     | | O  O |   | @  @ |   | >  < | |X|
 | Name 2     | Second description  |X|     | | \__/ |   | \__/ |   | \__/ | |X|
 |----------------------------------|X|     |  ------     ------     ------  |X|
 | Name 3     | Third description   | |     |  Name 1     Name 2     Name 3  | |
 |----------------------------------| |     |                                | |
 |            |                     | |     |  ------     ------     ------  | |
 | ...        | ...                 |v|     | | o  O |   | -  - |   | *  * | |v|
 ======================================     ====================================
```

I have found almost *perfect implementation* of what I need, named [**Ext.ux.grid.ExplorerView**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?49088-Ext.ux.grid.ExplorerView-Windows-Explorer-look-a-like-grid). However, the extension was developed for ExtJS versions 2.x (3.x), and cannot be reused for ExtJS 4.

I use a grid which is created as simple as:

```
Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    store: ...,
    columns: [{
        header: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
    }, {
        header: "Description",
        dataIndex: "description"
    }],
    tbar: [ ... ],
    bbar: [ ... ],
    listeners: { ... },
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        markDirty: false,
        listeners: { ... }
    }
});
```

I have tried to update `tpl` property of the inner view component, but nothing seems to work.

Do you have any idea of how to make the *dynamic switch between the views for a single grid panel*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was easily solved with wonderful *feature* for grid panel named "[**Tileview**](https://github.com/harrydeluxe/extjs-ux/blob/master/ux/grid/feature/Tileview.js)" developed by [**Harald Hanek**](https://github.com/harrydeluxe). The solution was specially developed for **ExtJS 4**.

The basic usage example is:

```
var grid = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    store: ...,
    columns: [{
        header: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
    }, {
        header: "Description",
        dataIndex: "description"
    }],
    tbar: [ ... ],
    bbar: [ ... ],
    listeners: { ... },
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        markDirty: false,
        listeners: { ... }
    },

    features: [Ext.create("Ext.ux.grid.feature.Tileview", {
        getAdditionalData: function(data, index, record, orig) {
            if (this.viewMode) {
                return {
                    name: record.get("name").toLowerCase(),
                };
            }
            return {};
        },
        viewMode: 'tileIcons',   // default view
        viewTpls: {
            tileIcons: [
                '<td class="{cls} ux-tileview-detailed-icon-row">',
                '<table class="x-grid-row-table">',
                    '<tbody>',
                    '<tr>',
                        '<td class="x-grid-col x-grid-cell ux-tileview-icon" style="background-image: url(&quot;...&quot;);">',
                        '</td>',
                        '<td class="x-grid-col x-grid-cell">',
                            '<div class="x-grid-cell-inner">{name}</div>',
                        '</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '</tbody>',
                '</table>',
                '</td>'
            ].join(""),

            mediumIcons: [ ... ].join(""),
            largeIcons: [ ... ].join("")
        }
    })]
});
```

To change the view we should just use `setView()` method, i.e.

```
grid.features[0].setView("tileIcons");
```

---

That's how the feature looks like in the real life.

- *Example of tile view:*

[image]

- *Example of image view:*

[image]

---

**References:**

- https://github.com/harrydeluxe/extjs-ux/blob/master/ux/grid/feature/Tileview.js -- Tileview sources
- https://github.com/harrydeluxe/extjs-ux -- *All Harald's extensions with screenshots*
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?183023-Thumbnails-in-Grid-with-switching-between-views -- *Feature discussion node on Sencha forum*
- http://harrydeluxe.github.com/extjs-ux/example/grid/tileview.html -- *Demo*

Comment: This plugin still not support for Extjs 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it like that. Instead, have a grid and a view in a card layout, the view gives you the ability to have pretty much any markup per item, here's a simple example:

```
Ext.define('Thing', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name']
});

Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: Thing,
        data: [{
            name: 'Name 1'
        }, {
            name: 'Name 2'
        }, {
            name: 'Name 3'
        }]
    });

    var gridActive = true;

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: document.body,
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        layout: 'card',
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Switch',
            handler: function(){
                var item;
                if (gridActive) {
                    item = panel.items.last();
                } else {
                    item = panel.items.first();
                }
                gridActive = !gridActive;
                panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(item);
            }
        }],
        items: [{
            border: false,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }],
            store: store
        }, {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            itemTpl: '<b>{name}</b>',
            store: store
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, Evan, for the great alternative solution. However, I suppose, having two views in memory may be not that efficient. I have found another good option. If you are interested, you may have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13111554/1249581).

Comment: With the tileview you're still having 2 views in memory, it's basically the same thing.

Comment: Not really. According to the sources, it simply replaces the template inside a view which underlies the grid.

Comment: It's pretty poor practice to be reaching in and modifying the internals like that, adding another view has hardly any extra overhead and is certainly a more correct and extensible way to do it.

Comment: @VisoN This answer is much cleaner, doesn't rely on undocumented features